# How to render Multi-Response GeoJSON tiles

Tags: leaflet, geojson, rendering, vector-tiles

I am using `TileStache` to combine and server multiple vector layers in a single Mutli-Response `GeoJSON` tile, which is basically all my individual tiles/layers (GeoJSONs containing either roads, pois, buildings) merged into one.

When `TileStache` combines the layers, the original layer name (like "roads" or "pois") is added before the features of that layer are included in the `GeoJSON`, so when I parse the tile to render it in leaflet (using the [`TileLayer.GeoJSON`](https://github.com/glenrobertson/leaflet-tilelayer-geojson) plugin) it doesn't recognize the objects in the `GeoJSON` file. It just skips over them and doesn't render anything.

This is what the sample response looks like:

```json
{
    "roads": {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": [{
            "geometry": {
                "type": "LineString",
                "coordinates": [
                    [73.12500, 33.61371],
                    [73.12432, 33.61462]
                ]
            },
            "type": "Feature",
            "id": "ff7274b342",
            "clipped": true,
            "properties": {
                "priority": 5.00000,
                "name": "Islamabad Highway"
            }
        }]
    },
    "boundary": {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": []
    },
    "pois": {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": [{
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [73.10332, 33.60876]
            },
            "type": "Feature",
            "id": "0d39282b10",
            "clipped": true,
            "properties": {
                "priority": 1,
                "name": "BENAZIR BHUTTO INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT ISLAMABAD"
            }
        }]
    },
    "cartographic": {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": [{
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPolygon",
                "coordinates": 
                    [

                        [
                            [73.10095, 33.61462],
                            [73.10065, 33.61438],
                            [73.09731, 33.61462],
                            [73.10095, 33.61462]
                        ]
                    ]
            },
            "type": "Feature",
            "id": "963cec5810",
            "clipped": true,
            "properties": {
                "category": 6,
                "priority": 5,
                "kind": "port places",
                "name": "BENAZIR BHUTTO INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT"
            }
        }
}
```

And this is the code I am using in Leaflet:

```js
var geojsonURL1 = 'http://localhost:8080/composite/{z}/{x}/{y}.json'; 
var geojsonTileLayer1 = new L.TileLayer.GeoJSON(geojsonURL1, { maxZoom:22,
        //clipTiles: true,
        unique: function (feature) {
            return feature.id; 
        }
    }, {
        style: style,
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            if (feature.properties) {
                var popupString = '<div class="popup">';
                for (var k in feature.properties) {
                    var v = feature.properties[k];
                    popupString += k + ': ' + v + '<br />';
                }
                popupString += '</div>';
                layer.bindPopup(popupString);
            }
            if (!(layer instanceof L.Point)) {
                layer.on('mouseover', function () {
                    layer.setStyle(hoverStyle);
                });
                layer.on('mouseout', function () {
                    layer.setStyle(style);
                });
            }
        }
    }
);

map.addLayer(geojsonTileLayer);
```

How can I render them in Leaflet? Are there any viable alternatives to render the GeoJSON tiles?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The so-called "multiresponse GeoJSON object" is **not** valid GeoJSON. Split the data before instantiating the Leaflet GeoJSON layers, e.g.:

```js
// Assuming that you've already fetched the data off the network
var data = {
  roads: {
    type: "FeatureCollection",
    features: .....
  },
  pois: {
    type: "FeatureCollection",
    features: .....
  },
  .......
};

for (var featureLayer in data) {
    console.log(featureLayer); // e.g. "roads", "pois", etc
    var geoJson = data[featureLayer]; // This is now a valid geojson object

    // Now we can spawn Leaflet layers based on valid GeoJSON
    var layer = L.geoJson(geoJson, {...}).addTo(map);
}
```

Comment: How can I store the JSON response I get in the variable when I am accessing the data using  `http://localhost:8080/composite/{z}/{x}/{y}.json`?

Comment: The problem is that you're not just fetching "multiresponse GeoJSON", you're fetching "multiresponse GeoJSON **tiles**". You might want to have a look at the [code for `TileLayer.GeoJSON`](https://github.com/glenrobertson/leaflet-tilelayer-geojson/blob/master/TileLayer.GeoJSON.js), and see how the `addTileData` method receives the geojson and creates features - you should be able to extend the `TileLayer.GeoJSON` class and wrap the behaviour of that method, so it can handle the payload. I've written a [gist](https://gist.github.com/IvanSanchez/6a084d2a748d190010aa) for inspiration.

Comment: You're right I am dealing with Tiles, I've updated the question to reflect that now. I am looking into the code for `TileLayer.GeoJSON` while taking inspiration from your gist.

Answer (score 6):

I am now using [Tangram](https://mapzen.com/documentation/tangram/) to display my tiles, `Tangram` allows me to parse the composite response with no issues at all, it can identify the layers with just the name I supply, and it has good documentation and support.